# An action skips the return block and then redirects to error page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

ASP.NET Core 2.0; After sending GET request (HttpClient) my program skips the return block in code and leaves the current action with redirection to Error page without catching exception. You can see video with problem online or download [here](http://spaces.ru/files/view/id54787431/list/-61451278/70190084-1/?Link_id=1389364) *Sorry about music in a video!*

```
    public IActionResult VKAuth()
    {
        bool ok = Request.Query.TryGetValue("code", out var value);
        if (!ok)
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("Error");
        else // ok == true, go here
        {
            try
            {
                GetAccessToken(value).Wait(); // it's ok
                return RedirectToActionPermanent("Deleting"); // skips this return block
            }
            catch
            {
                return RedirectToActionPermanent("Error");
            }
        }
    } // then program stops here and then next step is error action of controller

    private async Task GetAccessToken(string value)
    {
        string Json;
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual, SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls|SslProtocols.Tls11|SslProtocols.Tls12 })
            using (HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://oauth.vk.com/") })
                Json = await Client.GetStringAsync($"access_token?client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri={Domain}/{AuthRoute}&code=" + value);
        JsonTokenResponseModel TokenModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonTokenResponseModel>(Json);
        AccessToken = new UserAccessToken(TokenModel.access_token, TokenModel.expires_in);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
    public IActionResult Deleting()
    {
        VKChange();
        return View();
    }

    private async void VKChange()
    {
        try
        {
            await ClearPage();
            Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Success", "SocialSuicide"), true);
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Error", "SocialSuicide"), true);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
    public IActionResult Deleting()
    {
        Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("code", out string code);
        ViewData["Token"] = "https://oauth.vk.com/" + $"access_token?client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri={Domain}/{AuthRoute}&code=" + code;
        ViewData["WallScript"] = Method($"execute?code={ExecuteWallScript}");
        ViewData["ApiVersion"] = ApiVersion;
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult VKAuth()
    {
        bool ok = Request.Query.TryGetValue("code", out var value);
        if (!ok)
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("Error");
        else
        {
            Response.Cookies.Append("code", value);
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("Deleting", "SocialSuicide");
        }
    }
```

I still have a problem, I deleted all async methods.

Comment: which return statement it is missing

Comment: @Shyju I wrote it as comment in code. VKAuth method, in try block

Comment: I assume that you have an action called "Deleting" in the same controller?  If not, there is nothing to redirect to.  Also, it would be difficult to confirm that your GetAccessToken method is not failing since it doesn't return anything and doesn't seem to do anything (unless I'm missing something, it creates an AccessToken, which goes out of scope and stops existing as soon as it's created.)  Your issue may be in there.

Comment: @ElementalPete i have Deleting action and Deleting.cshtml in the project. AccessToken is a property, all data I get from GetAccessToken exist

Comment: @ElementalPete updated the post

Comment: Sorry, I just watched the video.  To me, it looks like you ARE redirecting to the Deleting action.  In deleting, you call VKChange, which could redirect you to that same Error controller if `await ClearPage()` threw an exception.  Try setting a breakpoint in VKChange to see whether that is working like you expect.  Since it is `async void` (which is not a best practice), the debugger is probably skipping right over that.  Unfortunately, without being able to read the error message from Visual Studio, I don't see anything obvious that would cause the error.